# Associating two values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a trouble with a calendar I'm doing with TV shows.

Basically, I want to output my days of the week and the shows aired for each day. (without doing 7 different queries obviously)

The following outputs the shows with an airdate between the beginning of the week and the end

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
FROM show_episode_airdate, show_episode
WHERE show_episode_airdate.airdate BETWEEN :weekbeginning AND :weekend AND show_episode.episode_id = show_episode_airdate.episode_id ");

$stmt->execute(array(':weekbeginning' => $begin_date, ':weekend' => $end_date));

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

}
```

This outputs the seven dates of the week.

```
foreach ($listofdays as $num=>$jour) {
     $date_table[$num] = date('m-d-Y',$weekbegin[0]+$num*DUREE_UN_JOUR);
     $daysoftheweek = $date_table[$num];
     var_dump($daysoftheweek);
    }
```

This outputs the following:

```
string '05-20-2013' (length=10)

string '05-21-2013' (length=10)

string '05-22-2013' (length=10)

string '05-23-2013' (length=10)

string '05-24-2013' (length=10)

string '05-25-2013' (length=10)

string '05-26-2013' (length=10)
```

I don't understand how to combine those two things to achieve what I'm after ??!

Comment: I'm cleaning it up right now.

Comment: Done. I speak both language and tend to mix it up a little bit :s

Comment: Ah don't worry, I've also seen `dutch x english` :)

Comment: You are using PDO, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my battle plan to solve this:

Use `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Loop over these and convert the dates from their string format into unix timestamps, probably by using `explode` and `mktime`:

```
foreach($rows as &$row) {
    $unix_airdate= mktime(...TODO);
    $row['unix_airdate']= $unix_airdate;
}
unset($row); //do not forget because $row was a reference
```

Then in the loop you already wrote, use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php `$filtered_rows= array_filter($rows, 'my_filter_function..TODO');` so that my_filter_function checks that the unix_airdate is between weekbegin and before the begin of next week.

Now go over the filtered array and output all shows. If you want them aggregated by day, loop over the days of the week and filter by day_begin and day_begin_next_day instead.

Comment: I don't quite understand all of your code but I will look into it, thanks.